# Smooth Shading makes object messed up?

Tags: shaders

[image]I'm creating some airplanes in Blender, and when I was modeling part of the wing, I used smooth shading. This made the part really messed up, like there was a bunch of faces (see images). anyone have any idea why? wireframe view looks normal.

[image: original (shade flat)]

[image: shade smooth (messed up)]

Comment: Most likely a normal problem (recalculate in edit mode with CTRL+SHIFT+N while every face is selected. Zero tickness faces also portray this kind of problem.
Could you add additional screenshots?. eg. wireframe view in face select mode.

Comment: @Delagone ctrl shift n made it much worse. added screenshots

Comment: It's also possible that you have too many verts.
Next thing I'd try is using the 'merge by distance' operation. ALT+M

Comment: worked, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alt+m>merge by distance. that fixed it.